# How to evaluate $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+6}} dx $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I was wondering if my answer, $$ 6\frac{x} {\sqrt{6}} - 6\ \arctan \frac{x} {\sqrt{6}} + C $$
is correct using trig substitution.

If it's wrong, may you help me correct it? Thanks!

Comment: You can always take the derivative and see if you get the integrand to test your solution.

Comment: $(6\frac{x} {\sqrt{6}} - 6\ \arctan \frac{x} {\sqrt{6}} + C)'=\frac{\sqrt6 x^2}{x^2+6}$

Comment: ohhhh i see, thank you!

Comment: Did you use $\, x=\sqrt6 \tan u \, $ as trig. substitution?

Comment: yes i did, but θ instead of u

Comment: Ok, that choice is up to you. Can you find an error in your work?

Comment: yup, i noticed the error  thank you!!

Comment: Rather than use a trig substitution, you could consider using a hyperbolic substitution, such as $x=\sqrt{6}\sinh u$ which makes the process a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+6}} =\int \sqrt{x^2 + 6}-\frac{6}{\sqrt{x^2 + 6}} dx $$

Let:$$x=\sqrt{6}\tan(u)\implies dx = \sqrt 6\sec^2(u)$$
Therfore:
$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+6}} = \int \left({6\sec(u)-\frac{6}{\sec(u)}}\right)\sec^2(u) du = \int 6 \sec^3(u) - 6 \sec{(u)} du = 6 \int \sec^3(u) - \sec(u) du $$
**we have :**
$$\int \sec^3(u) du = \sec(u)\tan(u) - \int \tan^2(u)\sec(u) du = \sec(u)\tan(u) - \int sec^3(u) - \sec(u) du  \implies \int sec^3(u)-\sec(u) du = \frac{1}{2}\left({\sec(u)\tan(u)- \ln|\sec(u)+\tan(u)|}\right)$$
**Finally**
$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+6}} = 3\left({\sec(u)\tan(u)- \ln|\sec(u)+\tan(u)|}\right)$$
Where : $u = \arctan\left({\frac{x}{\sqrt 6}}\right)$
and we have : $$\tan(\arctan(x))=x \\ \sec(\arctan(x))=\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\arctan(x))}=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

Therfore:

$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+6}} dx= 3\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{6}}-\ln\left({\frac{x}{\sqrt 6} + \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{6}}}\right)}\right) =\boxed{\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{6+x^2} -3\ln(x+\sqrt{6+x^2}) + c}$$

Comment: thank you!!but like i don't get the first part

Comment: @RURIKO integration by parts

Comment: do i not just plug in the x, to the equation?

Answer (score 0):

$\int{\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{x^2+6})}dx}$

= $\int{\frac{x^2+6-6}{\sqrt{x^2+6}}dx}$

=$\int{\frac{x^2+6}{\sqrt{x^2+6}}dx}$-$\int{\frac{6}{\sqrt{x^2+6}}dx}$

=$\int{\sqrt{x^2+6}dx}$ -6$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+6}}dx}$

=$\frac{1}{2}$x$\sqrt{x^2+6}$ +3 $log{(x+\sqrt{x^2+6})}$- 6$log(x+\sqrt{x^2+6})$
+C